# How do I properly test this method with OCMock?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, stub, ocmock, stubbing

I'm new to OCMock and i'm trying to test if a method is called, except I want the method to be a stub since it contains other loading methods I do not care to test in the current test.

```
- (void)setUp
{
    self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
   self.rootViewController = nil;
}

- (void)test_ViewDidLoad_DidCallLoadChildViewControllers
{
    id mockRootViewController = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:self.rootViewController];

    [(RootViewController*)[mockRootViewController stub] loadChildViewControllers];
    [(RootViewController*)[mockRootViewController stub] updateMainNavigation];

    [[mockRootViewController expect] loadChildViewControllers];

    // Force the view to load
    self.rootViewController.view;

    [mockRootViewController verify];
}
```

And here is the method that is getting called:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadChildViewControllers];
    [self updateMainNavigation];
}
```

For some reason the test is failing as if it is never called (yet I can step thru it and verify that it is getting called, as well as it being a stub.

Here is the error:

```
OCPartialMockObject[RootViewController]: expected method was not invoked: loadChildViewControllers
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing this line:

```
[(RootViewController*)[mockRootViewController stub] loadChildViewControllers];
```

When you `expect` that method, it has the side effect of stubbing it, so the `stub` is unnecessary. I suspect what's happening is that your `stub` recorder is swallowing the invocation before the `expect` recorder has a chance to match it.